# How to set up an alert list panel in Grafana?

Tags: monitoring, grafana

I've seen the following widget from Grafana demo page:

[image]

And I can't understand how to do this. I've added a couple of alerts to my dashboard, yet I don't see how do I make them visible in "Alert List" widget I've added before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should show up automatically. It takes a few seconds before the alert is run and you have to save the dashboard and refresh the page. I just tested this locally and it worked.

The other thing to check is what options are chosen on the Options tab. Have you checked one of the filtering options that is hiding your alert or are there more alerts than 10 which is the default max:

[image]